# Shorten text codes

Tags: cryptography

My question is more of cryptographic matter than programming.

I have codes of 5 chars each, that can be concatenated in pairs. The result is a code of 10 chars.

The problem is that the database field where I must store these values is only 6 chars width, and i'd prefer not to resize it.

Is there a known method or algorithm which could shorten the pairs of value, to change from 10 chars to 6 chars max ? The result can be made of any printable chars (preferably ASCII), and must avoid any duplicated values for two distinct  pairs of codes.

Another solution may be shortening the 5 chars codes to 3 chars, but the remaining problem is also about no duplicates allowed when concatenated by pairs.

Thank you for any idea. I tried several solution (including Base64 encoding !) but my results are always too long, or they include duplicated values.

Comment: This question is not answerable without knowing how many distinct values of a character pair are possible.

Comment: Can you update the question with any constraints that exist on the 5-character codes?  E.g., is there a registry of legal codes?  If not, are there limits on the range of values each character in a code may take?  Are those limits the same for each position within the code?

Comment: Well, the code values are submitted by our customer. We have Codes and SubCodes, with a specific list of Codes and a specific list of SubCodes. Each Code can be concatenated with some SubCodes (but not all of them) as the SubCodes are used to give details about the event specified by the Code. For example (not real) : Code = DSCNT (Discount) Subcode can be AAAAA (10% discount) or BBBBB (15% discount) and so on. So concatenation will give DSCNTAAAAA or DSCNTBBBBB ...

Comment: We need to know the specific lists of codes and subcodes, edit the question   and add that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with cryptography. It should probably be tagged [information-theory](/questions/tagged/information-theory).

There are 97 printable ASCII characters, so the maximum amount of information that you can store in 6 chars is 39.6 bits (=6 × log<sub>2</sub>(97)). If you spread the same amount of information across 10 characters, then you only can only carry 3.96 bits in each character. That means you can use an alphabet of 15 characters for your codes (e.g., uppercase letters from A to O).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact, I should have specified that I am looking for an algorithmic solution using some specific method to shorten the codes, rather than an arbitrary matching table with corresponding values. But your answer is precise, clear and appreciated. Thank you.